# Запятые в предложении: "Мы выясним(,) почему это случилось(,) и примем меры"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Подскажите, будет ли ставиться запятая перед "почему" и союзом "и" в предложении:

> Мы выясним(,) почему это случилось(,) и примем меры.

Answer (score 3):

*"Мы выясним, почему это случилось, и примем меры"* - запятые выделяют придаточное изъяснительное предложение. Если его изъять, получится: "Мы выясним  и примем меры".